# Position estimation from photo fingerprinting

Tags: localization

i want to make 3d position and position change estimation from photos taken from flying robot. I need suggestions for fast photo matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an optical flow system: a camera that by recognizing the movement of patterns can estimate the movement of the camera target relative to the camera.  You can implement your own optical flow algorithm through the use of [OpenCV](http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b05/notes/CS%20223-B%20T1%20stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf), a popular computer vision library.

However, it's more likely that you'll want to use existing sensors with SoCs for optical flow built in, such as those found in optical mice. An example commonly used with quadcopters is this [ADNS3080 breakout board](http://copter.ardupilot.com/wiki/common-optional-hardware/common-optical-flow-sensors-landingpage/common-mouse-based-optical-flow-sensor-adns3080/), or [this one](https://store.3drobotics.com/products/px4flow) from 3DRobotics.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. But im looking for an matching algorithm that estimates position from photos which is taken from different devices. Photos not taking from same device and i have to find relation and than estimate position